# Abstract class extending concrete classes

Tags: java, abstract-class, extend

I have an [abstract class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) that extends a concrete class. But I'm confused about how to use it. How am I supposed to instantiate the concrete class with the methods in the abstract class like I would normally do the other way around? Or is there another way to instantiate the classes?

Comment: add some code so we can help you

Comment: I'm confused how to use your imaginary code as well

Comment: You just need to extend it again.

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970980/abstract-class-extends-concrete-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a sort of implementation. What I mean by this is like:
Let's say you have an Animal class. The `Animal` class has a method names `jump()` and then another class that extends `Mammal`. The `Mammal` class is abstract. What my understanding is that you would like whatever class extends `Mammal` to HAVE to override the `jump()` method. This is what I believe is your question. To achieve this, I would say to create an abstract method and call that in the original method. What I mean by this is like so:

```
public class Animal
{
    public final String name;
    public final int weight;

    public Animal(String name, int weight)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void jump()
    {
        System.out.println(name + " Jumped");
    }
}
```

Then you have the Mammal class:

```
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal
{
    public Mammal(String name, int weight)
    {
        super(name, weight);
    }

    public abstract void jumpMammal();

    @Override
    public final void jump()
    {
        jumpMammal();
    }
}
```

If any class attempts to override the `Mammal` class, they are required to override the `jumpMammal()` method, therefore running in the `jump()` method.

Answer (score 21):

An abstract class always extends a concrete class (`java.lang.Object` at the very least). So it works the same as it always does. If you want to instantiate it, you will have to subclass it with a concrete implementation of those abstract methods and instantiate it through the concrete class.

Just like you always do. This isn't a special case.

Answer (score 1):

For example, let’s say we have an abstract class, Foo, extending the *fooFather* class.

```
public abstract class Foo extends FooFather{


}
```

Then we create a subclass that extends *Foo* like this:

```
public class Foo2 extends Foo{


}
```

And initialize it like this:

```
Foo aFoo = new Foo2();
```

Comment: Re *"initialize it"*: That needs to be more precise. It isn't the class that is initialised.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*